# How to count microoperations/cycles involved in a single instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, benchmarking

I'm trying to understand how to benchmark a single instruction and came up the following Intel benchmarking article: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-32-ia-64-benchmark-code-execution-paper.pdf

So we use `rdtsc` to read the number of clock cycles. But as specified in Intel manual `17.17 TIME-STAMP COUNTER` earlier cpus  increments it with fixed rate that may differ from current clock frequency.

> For Pentium 4 processors, Intel Xeon processors [...]: the time-
>   stamp counter increments at a constant rate. That rate may be set
>   by the maximum core-clock to bus-clock ratio of the processor or 
>   may be set by the maximum resolved frequency at which the 
>   processor is booted.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a way to get the actual CPU clock cycles like `rdtsc` got for older cpus?
2. Is there a way to measure the number of uops some instruction involved? Particularly I want yo compare the difference of uops required when the instruction is being pipelined and not (e.g. when the same instruction is repeated when loop is unrolled)

Comment: `rdtsc` is not useful to time a single instruction even on CPUs that have it, because you need to measure its throughput and latency separately.  Performance is not 1-dimensional and you can't model it by giving each instruction 1 cost and adding them up.  [How many CPU cycles are needed for each assembly instruction?](//stackoverflow.com/a/44980899).  Also `rdtsc` has a lot of overhead compare to a simple 1-uop / 1-cycle latency instruction like `add`.

Comment: Count uops by putting an instruction (repeated multiple times either dependent on each other or independent) in a loop and subtracting loop overhead.  (Read HW perf counters for `uops_issued` and `uops_executed` with `perf stat` or whatever).  My answer on [RDTSCP in NASM always returns the same value](//stackoverflow.com/q/54621381) shows how with an example.   I think http://uops.info/ has their benchmark framework open-source, so you can see how they test instructions for which ports the uops for a given instruction can run on, etc.

Comment: BTW, instructions generally decode separately; **there aren't more uops depending on whether it's part of the latency critical path or not**.  That's not even known until issue/rename and execute time, long after the uops are generated by the decoders.  See https://agner.org/optimize/ for CPUs as far back as Pentium.  (Which *didn't* decode to uops; complex instructions just stalled the in-order pipeline and/or couldn't pair.)

Comment: There can be effects like not *executing* all of the uops; apparently SnB-family can drop the FLAG-merging uop in a variable count shift if that FLAGS value is overwritten  without being read.  (Intel's optimization manual mentions this.)  And uops can get replayed (dispatched again) if they use the result of a load that misses in cache.  But all the uops have to *issue* from the front-end into the out-of-order back-end.

Comment: @PeterCordes I have a question regarding execution of multiple `add` (for instance) instructions in a row. Intel manual at 2.2.3 specifies that Intel Core cpus have `Three arithmetic logical units`. So does it mean that after fetching/decondiong execution back-end can dispatch up to 3 uops to different ALUs making it possible to execute 3 arithmetic instructions in the same cycle. In my understanding as soon as each ALU is done it dispatches the result back to the back end making the instruction retired.

Comment: Haswell and later have 4 ALU execution ports, so `add`'s reciprocal throughput = 0.25c.  But yes, Intel since Core2 at least has 3 per clock `add` throughput, if there isn't a data dependency that forces one to wait for the output of the other.  They don't have to have fetched and decoded together, but sure.

Comment: "dispatch" in Intel's technical terminology is when the scheduler (RS) sends a uop to an execution port.  Yes, when it completes it signals back to the RS that it can be marked executed and dropped from the RS, staying only in the ROB until retirement (which has to wait for all earlier instructions to retire, because retirement happens in-order, unlike execution, in groups of up to 4 or 8 per clock)

Comment: If you're trying to understand the basics of how instructions decode and execute, maybe have a look at [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/349972/how-does-a-single-thread-run-on-multiple-cores/350024#350024) and some of the performance / cpu microarchitecture links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info, e.g. **http://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/ is a great intro to superscalar pipelined CPUs**, and covers a bit about out-of-order execution and modern CPUs